# Iterating through map of objects in terraform modules

Tags: terraform

I need to build 2-3 vnets and under single vnet, we need to build 2 subnets.

Below is my code:

```
**variables.tf**

variable "vnet_config" {

  type = map(object({
    vnet_name      = string
    address_space  = list(string)
  }))
}

    **vnet.auto.tfvars**
    
    vnet_config = {
    
      vnet1 = {
        vnetname       = "bupa1"
        address_space  = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
      },
    
      vnet2 = {
        vnetname      = "bupa2"
        address_space  = ["192.168.0.0/24"]
      }

}

****main.tf****

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.98.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg1" {
  name     = "rg1"
  location = "West Europe"
}

module vnet {
  source              = "./vnet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg1.name
  for_each            = var.vnet_config
  vnet_name           = each.value.vnetname
  address_space       = each.value.address_space
  
}

module "subnet" {
  source                  = "./subnet"
  resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  vnet_name               = module.vnet.vnet_name
  subnet_name             = "test20"
  subnet_address_prefixes = "10.0.1.0/24"
}
```

**output.tf**

```
output "vnet_id" {
  description = "The id of the newly created vNet"
  value       = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.id
}

output "vnet_name" {
  description = "The Name of the newly created vNet"
  value       = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
}

output "vnet_location" {
  description = "The location of the newly created vNet"
  value       = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.location
}

output "vnet_address_space" {
  description = "The address space of the newly created vNet"
  value       = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.address_space
}
```

**vnet_name               = module.vnet.vnet_name**

The above statement will not work as there are two vnets getting created in the vnet module.

I have modules for vnet and subnet already created and I am calling them to create vnets and subnets.

Please can you help me in resolving this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Add `for_each` to `module "subnet"` and use the same variable as in `module "vnet"`. Then, when referencing the output of the module, just add `module.vnet.vnet_name[each.value.vnetname]`. I think. :)

Comment: What error exactly do you get?

Comment: @Marcin: please find the error :    Error: Invalid value for module argument
│
│   on main.tf line 35, in module "subnet4":
│   35:   vnet_name               = module.vnet.vnet_name
│
│ The given value is not suitable for child module variable "vnet_name" defined at subnet\variables.tf:41,1-21: string    
│ required.

Comment: Do you have an output `vnet_name` defined in the `vnet` module? If so, can you add that to the question as well?

Comment: @MarkoE have added the output.tf for vnet module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a unique reference for each subnet. And for each one you could create multiple copies, one for each vnet.

```
module "subnet1" {
 for_each = module.vnet

 ...

 vnet_name = each.value.vnet_name                  
 subnet_name             = "test10"
}
```

```
module "subnet2" {
 for_each = module.vnet

 ...

 vnet_name = each.value.vnet_name                  
 subnet_name             = "test20"
}
```

---

Since you used **for_each**, If you want to refer to a single vnet use,
module."NAME"["KEY"].ATTRIBUTE e.g.
**module.vnet["vnet1"].vnet_name**

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I have implemented the above code. It is now creating the same subnet for both the vnets. I wanted subnet to be created in a single vnet. Please can you help me in that or suggest a better way to achieve this solution

Comment: Of course, glad to help. Did you use different values for each subnet like address_prefixes and subnet_name? If you want to refer to a single vnet use, module.<NAME>[<KEY>] e.g. azurerm_resource_group.rg["a_group"]

Comment: e.g. module.vnet["vnet1"].vnet_name